# I want to understand when to use @property vs instance variables

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, properties, ivar

I've been learning Obj-C for a while now, and I have a fundamental question. There seems to be an inordinate number of 'self's everywhere in my code. I believe it is down to a basic question about the differences between two ways to declare and use variables.

Attached is some code that supports my question. In it, there are two variables declared (in different places) and used to do the same thing in a method: optionA and optionB. I am unsure which one to use. I thought it might be because using "property", as shown with optionB, would ensure that I get the accessors (setter and getter), but I see that optionA apparently has a setter.

I prefer optionA because it means I don't need "self" all over the place, but I want to understand the implications of using one over the other.

In a program I am working on, all variables are declared as properties (a la optionB below), but I have to use 'self' when accessing them. I am wondering if that is proper, and just an artifact of the right way to do things, or whether I am completely off the mark and should be using another form, like that of optionA.

When/Why would someone declare a variable between the curly braces of the interface (like optionA)?

I searched through the questions answered but don't find any that quite tell me what I am trying to learn here. But I can't quite find the info I am looking for in other questions or their answers.

I have a picture of the code here (but I don't have the prestige points to be allowed to link it directly into this message, apparently): http://i1127.photobucket.com/albums/l631/GenericImage/headerQueryOBJC.jpg

here are listings:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    IBOutlet NSTextField *optionA;

}

- (IBAction)happy:(id)sender; 
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window; 
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *optionB; 
@end
```

implementation

```
#import "AppDelegate.h" 

@implementation AppDelegate 
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification 
{ 
     // Insert code here to initialize your application 
} 


-(IBAction)happy:(id)sender
{  
    [optionA setStringValue:@":-)"]; 
    [[self optionB] setStringValue:@":)"]; 
} 

@end
```

Comment: Thanks viking!  How did you fix the formatting? I didn't quite understand what I was supposed to do...

Comment: If you just select all the lines of code and hit the code button in the editor, it will format the code that way for you. (The actual way you format code like that is by putting four spaces before each line. But the editor can do it for you, so it's less work that way.)

Comment: Thank you, Chuck! I will try that technique next time. I was confused and tried to use the back-tick and eight spaces...to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

There are many scenarios where the use of a **property** is equivalent to the use of a **variable**.

In the scenario that you describe, where your variable & property refer to a user interface object (IBOutlet) and is linked to Interface Builder, you don't see that much the difference, mainly because your variable will point to the same object throughout the life-cycle of its owner (or controller, in apple's jargon)

Some of the things that can affect the scenario are:
- The use of ARC
- property modifiers (assign, copy...)
- bindings

If you use ARC it's more likely that you don't see clearly the difference. But when not using ARC, and having a property with 'copy' or 'assign' modifier allows you to see the difference.

```
@property (retain) NSString *string;

string = someOtherString;
```

In this example, prior to assigning someOtherString, the ivar associated to the property is released from its previous contents (and its retain count is decremented). If you were not using the property you would need to handle the retaincount yourself in each assignment, to avoid writing on deallocated memory.

Another example: if you use bindings in your projects, you will see that using ivars is not enough, because they are not KVC/KVO compliant.

**Conclusion:** If you understand the underlying concepts, you'll be able to know when **properties** and **variables** are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks! As I read more and more responses (here and around the site) related to my question, it is quite clear that I do not yet "understand the underlying concepts"  Which is, as I suspected, part of my problem! I may delete this question yet...

Comment: Your question is nicely written, so I would leave it.

Comment: For the purpose of my original query, is the above example robust enough to use either optionA or optionB? ie. can I implement the optionA technique above without worry that I am developing a bad habit, or moving away from Apple's intended use of the language?  I don't write programs professionally, yet, so the consequences are all my own at this stage of the game. One thing I would like to do is replicate the larger program I am writing, implement changes and then have two versions that I can use to compare and contrast as things move forward. thoughts?

Comment: For your specific example, both options are OK. Don't worry too much, I can assure that if you write a few programs you'll get a feel of these 'underlying concepts' much better.